# what is happening in the memory and cpu under the hood when printf a std::string incorrectly?

Tags: c++, string, printf

We know that, `printf` function can only print POD type like int, char, char *, etc. And if we pass a `std::string` type without calling its `c_str()` member function, then the program shall be aborted by raising `ILLEGAL INSTRUCTION` signal.

Like the easy code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string str("hello world");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

If you use `g++ -g` to build it, and set `ulimit -c unlimited`, when you run the program, it will core dump at runtime. And if you run gdb on the core file, gdb tells you that this program went wrong at line `std::string str("hello world");`, pretty weird.
Here is the screenshots.
[image: Running program]
[image: Gdb debugging]
So I am considering the mechanisms under this phenomenon.

1. How does printf raise a illegal instruction? Like std::string memory composition, cpu illegal instruction, etc...
2. why does gdb claims at the upper line of code went wrong instead of the printf line?

I know this might be a trivial problem, but it is very cool to understand its mechanisms.

Comment: `will core at runtime` Please start with learning what a core dump actually is, instead of using "to core" as verb. And printfs does not "raise illegal instructions"

Comment: `%s` assumes a pointer to a null-terminated string. When you pass `std::string` that's not what `printf` is getting. It's getting a pointer to something else. So `printf` with `%s` will keep reading bytes, as if they were string characters, from the buffer at that address until it finds a null byte. There's some likelihood that it will trespass into memory it doesn't have access to before encountering that null.

Comment: What do you mean by *the upper line of code*? Do you mean the line of code before the `printf`?

Comment: It will invoke a segmentation fault, not an illegal instruction, which occurs when you dereference an invalid function pointer.

Comment: 'it is very cool to understand its mechanisms.' - OK, here's you chance to be cool.  Set it up and trace through the call with your debugger.  What would be uncool is to ask SO to explain your own UB, since it will be different in different environments.

Comment: @stackptr Where is a function pointer? ... And the behaviour is just UB, there is no guarantee for any specific error.

Comment: @deviantfan see I modified my description. And for the next, I just mean when we use printf in this way, the OS will raise a ILLEGAL INSTRUCTION signal.

Comment: Will it?  I see nasal demons in your near future.

Comment: @richard.g As I just said to stackptr, there is no guarantee for any specific error. Anything can happen. It could even work correctly, sometimes.

Comment: @lurker yes, the ' std::string str("hello world")' line.

Comment: @deviantfan I know that it doesn't have to be any specific error, but on most machines, a segmemtation fault is raised when  this happens.

Comment: How did you get your code to compile? As it stands, it should give a warning about the `printf` not being prototyped. If you include the correct header for `printf`, then you'll get a compile error disallowing the passing of `std::string` type for a `%s` specifier (*e.g.*, `foo.cpp:7:23: error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘std::string {aka class std::basic_string<char>}’ through ‘...’`).

Comment: @lurker yes, the compiler complains, but unfortunately, sometimes there are too many warnings, and we are very possible to ignore some of them.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to ignore the warnings, especially if there are many.

Comment: @lurker, yeah, but that's what's happening anyway. Maybe I can use some memory inspection tool to check on this. ;-) Seems that there is few people actually cares its mechanism. Is this really context, compiler and machine defined, or no matter what, the program behaves the same.

Comment: As far as explanation of why it fails, see my very first comment. The two answers posted give even more detail.

Comment: @richard.g: no, it _appears to you_ to behave the same.  Tomorrow, it may be different. Because it's undefined behavior.  Many people care about the mechanism. In fact, since I recognize the names of most of the commenters, most of us know the mechanisms.  Our point is that your question is based on false premise.  (We know this because we know the mechanisms)

Comment: In part answer to one of your questions, as your program invokes undefined behaviour the standard allows it to do so at any point in the execution. Including before where you actually do the bad thing. If any part of the program invokes undefined behaviour, the whole program is undefined

Answer (score 2):

When format string of argument of `printf` contains `%s` and corresponding argument is not a pointer to `char` terminated by a `\0`, the behavior of program is `undefined`.

Typically `std::string` would contain some pointers containing information of actual data (start pointer, end pointer/size etc) and the data may or may not be null-terminated. So attempt to print an `std::string` using `C` function is an undefined behavior. (Note that: Type of `std::string::c_str` is `const char *` and null terminated and thus can be printed using `printf`)

`printf` has no way to check the validity of arguments at compile time and it consumes arguments. If data it reads is not readable, trap implementation may be implemented or it may crash or may work as expected.

Comment: You can't print a std::string in C. C doesn't have std::string

Comment: @TomTanner You are right. My point was using C standard function. Let me rephrase it.

Comment: @MohitJain Any docs on the "the behavior of program is undefined" part?

Answer (score 1):

The C++03 standard says it's undefined behaviour to pass something that's not a POD to a varargs (...) parameter. In fact gcc gives you a warning that the program will crash (but compiles it successfully anyway).

Specifically, this means

```
printf("This doesn't use the arguments", std::string(""));
```

could crash.

Incidentally, in C++11, this is conditionally supported with implementation defined with implementation defined semantics, but still comes under 'best to avoid'.

There's no mechanism and no guarantee of any particular behaviour. It could crash, it could work, it could reformat your hard drive. It's really not interesting to see what a particular compiler is doing.